# Why does this print method work? shouldn't it fail?

Tags: java, println

I have a function which returns a String, but first I check if the String is null, if it is, I return null.

my function

`String decode(String input);`
this can return null if input is null
so, if I do `decode(null())`, it should return `null`, right?
and `println(null)` shouldn't print `"null"`, right?

A link to the code, which can be run: http://ideone.com/bLreXJ

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Testing
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String input = null;
        // get input in some manner

        input = "www.me%20.com";
        System.out.println(decode(input));  // returns "www.me .com"

        input = "https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=java%20hi%20there";
        System.out.println(decode(input)); // returns "https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=java hi there"

        input = " ";
        System.out.println(decode(input)); // returns ""

        input = null;
        System.out.println(decode(input)); // returns "null" , but why?

        // System.out.println(null); // this fails because println doesn't accept null
    }

    public static String decode(String input){
        if(input == null)
            return null;
        String[] strArr = input.split("%20");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        for(String a : strArr){
            sb.append(a).append(" ");
        }
        return sb.toString().trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `System.out.println(null)` will print `null` literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote

```
    // System.out.println(null); // this fails because println doesn't accept null
```

are you sure about this?

`PrintStream.println` calls `String.valueOf`, which converts the `null` to the string `"null"`.

Comment: Ah, that's the explanation I needed. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that `null` does not have a type, so this results in a compiler error, because java doesn't know which overloaded method to call. First cast the value to a String: `System.out.println((String) null);`